# Pulling another row if it meets criteria from the first pulled row

Tags: sql, sql-server

Need to compare some accounts, which some people have two of, an admin account and a regular account. These admin accounts list their regular account as their manager and all of the admin accounts start with a 1. How would I make it pull the row of the manager as well as the row with the admin account?

I've tried using Where and Where Exists, I can't seem to think of a way of using Select to get the manager as well, a bit of tunnel vision I think right now.

```
SELECT *
FROM 
    view
WHERE id like '1%'
```

The expected result should pull every account beginning with 1 and their managers.

So if Bob has two rows in the account table, one being named 1Bob and the other being named Bob, and 1Bob lists Bob as the manager in the 1Bob manager column, the result should pull 1Bob and Bob

```
Input
+--------+-------+---------+
| Number |  ID   | Manager |
+--------+-------+---------+
|      1 | 1Bob  | Bob     |
|      2 |  Bob  | Cindy   |
|      3 | Cindy | Derek   |
+--------+-------+---------+

Result

+--------+------+---------+
| Number |  ID  | Manager |
+--------+------+---------+
|      1 | 1Bob |  Bob    |
|      2 |  Bob | Cindy   |
+--------+------+---------+
```

Comment: @GordonLinoff Best description of desired results is edited in if it wasn't clear enough

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read up on how to provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)  You may also benefit from [this helpful article on what is considered necessary for an SQL question](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an `exists` clause:

```
select v.*
from view v
where v.id like '1%' or
      exists (select 1 from view v2 where v2.manager = v.id and v2.id like '1%');
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like your data architecture is in need of some serious help. But given the description you could kludge this together along these lines.

```
SELECT *
FROM 
    view v
join view v2 on v2.id = substring(v.Manager, 2, len(v.Manager))
WHERE v.id like '1%'
```

--EDIT--
Attempting to update this with the new understanding of the table structure.

Comment: This works for the most part, except it's returning all of the employees of the manager of the 1Account, so instead of it returning just 1Bob and Bobs rows, it's returning 1Bob and joining it with all of Bobs employees. I've updated the main post to show what the results should look like.

Comment: Then just change the join predicate to join on v.Manager = v2.ID. Still...this data scheme is very problematic. It violates 1NF multiple times. Once for shoving two piece of data into a single column. 1Bob should be two columns. And again for using data that might change as the key and relational information. What happens if Bob changes his name to Steve?

Comment: Yeah I'm aware of how bad of an idea it is, it's a bit of a long story mixed with bureaucracy and such.

Comment: I feel your pain there. Sometimes you just have to plug your nose and plow ahead no matter bad it smells. Good luck!!!